# Large cardinals and $V$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I am confused by something: $\mu$ is a large cardinal if $\lambda<\mu\Rightarrow 2^{\lambda}<\mu$ and any union of less than $\mu$ sets of size less than $\mu$ is less than $\mu$. On Wikipedia it says "large cardinals are understood in the context of the von Neumann universe $V$". But isn't $V$ constructed precisely using the power set and union operations?

I know we cannot prove the existence of large cardinals in $\sf ZFC$, but if we adopted "a large cardinal exists in $V$" why doesn't this create a contradiction? How can something exist in $V$ without being reachable using the tools $V$ is built from?

Comment: @Sanath: While the edit doesn't hurt; I think that if your edit consists only of TeXifying ZFC into $\sf ZFC$ or $\rm ZFC$ (or similar theories), then it might not be needed after all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I apologize if the edit seemed redundant. I wanted to make the question look more professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, and a delicate point.

The von Neumann hierarchy does not *construct* the universe. The universe is given to us, by the gods, by ourselves, by whoever wrote the text. What is true, however, is that given a universe of $\sf ZF$ then we can prove that that von Neumann hierarchy is a hierarchy which covers the entire universe. That is, every set in $V$ is in some $V_\alpha$.

Ask yourself, if the von Neumann hierarchy actually constructs the universe, then where do the ordinals come from? Why can we continue after reaching ordinals like the first $\aleph$ fixed point? Or the first $\beth$ fixed point? Or the first ordinal which is both an $\aleph$ and a $\beth$ fixed point?

No. The universe is given.

We can, however, stretch this slightly more. Suppose that we have a universe satisfying $\sf ZF-Fnd$, then the von Neumann hierarchy *constructs* an inner model $V$ which satisfies $\sf ZF$. Why can we say construct in this context? Because we construct an inner model, but this means that a universe is given to us already.

So if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, it already exists in the universe. The point is that the first step any set of cardinality $\kappa$ appears in the von Neumann construction is $\kappa$. It doesn't imply any contradiction, much like how the existence of an inaccessible cardinal implies the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ doesn't imply a contradiction either.

And just to finish with a small point, large cardinals don't always have to be inaccessible. See about Rowbottom and Jonsson cardinals. Or even actual cardinals, see about $0^\#$ (read: zero sharp) which is in fact a real number.

Comment: About your last paragraph, that is why I distinguish between a "large cardinal" (which is, indeed, a cardinal), and a large cardinal statement (or a statement of "large cardinal character"), such as the existence of $0^\sharp$.

Comment: Andres, that's a nice distinction. I think I'll try to adopt it. Although I can't say I'm optimistic about the success of this sort of attempt. :-P

Comment: Andres: By the way, in this context, are Jonsson/Rowbottom cardinals large cardinals, or large cardinal character cardinals?

Comment: I would not call them large cardinals as they are not inaccessible. Same as $0^\sharp$. But of course being Jónsson is a large cardinal property.